# Problems with staggered Image and CheckBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have problems with the placement of the Image and the CheckBox. They are placed in a staggered way. I want them to be placed on a straight horizontal line. You can see the problem on the image below.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/98/)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="modalDialog">

        <form>
            <hr/><br/>

            <label>Add checkBox</label>
            <br />

            <input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
            <input type="button" id="btnSaveCheckBox" value="_Ok" />
            <br />

        </form>

    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {

        $('#modalDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            position: 'center'
        });

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({showWeek:true, firstDay:1});

    // Add a new checkBox
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

    function addCheckbox(name) {
        var container = $('#modalDialog');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;

        $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', class: 'allcheckbox', id: 'cb' + id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
        $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb' + id, class: 'allcheckbox',  text: name }).appendTo(container);


   $('<img />', { "src": "/Pages/Images/trashDialog.png", "class": "removeCheckBoxDialog" }).appendTo(container);    

        $('<br/>').appendTo(container);


    } 

    $('#modalDialog').on('click','.removeCheckBoxDialog', function (e) {            
        $('#'+$(this).prev().attr('for')).remove();
        $(this).next('br').remove();
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }); 


});
```

CSS:

```
/*Style of a Modal Dialog*/
#modalDialog {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid black 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px #828282;
}

.removeCheckBoxDialog {    
    border: 1px solid Red !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:90%;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) replicating the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.removeCheckBoxDialog {    
    border: 1px solid Red !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    /*margin-left:90%;*/
}

br{
    clear:both;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/99/)**

Comment: @Anton haha it keeps happening :) I thought the same way when someone else post before me

Comment: How can I make more space between the checkBoxes ??

Comment: do you mean checkbox and label text for that add css #modalDialog input.allcheckbox{margin-right:10px;}